# Trying to iterate through a list of a list of dictionaries and update values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am trying to create a data structure as follows:

```
import random

class Person:
    DNA = [[{}] * 100] * 10 # 10 chromosomes, 100 genes in each?

    def __init__(self):
        DNA = Persona.DNA

        # Generate random variables to create DNA
        for chromosome, _ in DNA:
            for gene, _ in chromosome:
                if random.randint(0, 3) == 3:
                    DNA[chromosome][gene]['Str'] = 3

        self.DNA = DNA
```

I get the error, "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)", but I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Why can't I enumerate?

Comment: `DNA = [[{}] * 100] * 10` that is bad: you're duplicating the dict reference. In the end you get 1000 times the same data.

Comment: `for chromosome, _ in DNA`: there is only 1 value issed by `DNA`

Comment: then `for gene,_ in chromosome:` you'll get the same error again but after that you're modifying the dict you're iterating upon... your code is wrong, wrong, wrong

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
when gene,_ in chromosome:

Comment: my bad. But your code is very wrong. Oh, and you're reusing the same class-scope `DNA` without creating a copy: every instance gets the same data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Applying all of @Jean-Francois 's suggestions:

```
import random

class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        DNA = [[dict() for _ in range(100)] for _ in range(10)]

        # Generate random variables to create DNA
        for chromosome in DNA:
            for gene in chromosome:
                if random.randint(0, 3) == 3:
                    gene['Str'] = 3

        self.DNA = DNA
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.DNA = [[dict(Str=3) if random.randint(0,3) == 3 else dict()
                     for _ in range(100)]
                    for _ in range(10)]
```

The main issues with the code are:

1. To get an `(idx, item)` tuple from an array, use `enumerate`. E.g., `for i, chromosome in enumerate(DNA):`. Otherwise, looping on the list only yields the items within that list.
2. You're duplicating objects, not making new ones. This'll bite you, since you don't have 1,000 dictionaries, you have 1 dictionary, referenced in 100 lists, all of which are referenced in 10 other lists. Any get/set to that one dictionary, or one of those 100 lists, will show up everywhere else that that object is referenced.
3. Likewise, the class variable gets created once, and you then refer to it from each instance of that class, meaning there will only ever be one Person's DNA. Just like you need a new list and dict for each spot in the DNA array, you need a new DNA strand object for each person.

Comment: I'm glad I haven't answered, since my answer would have been a lazy one compared to this :)

Comment: I'm happy to provide verbose answers, just want to give a little credit where due since you got here first and made all the right points.

Comment: fine by me. you're working hard to get the "low hanging fruit", keep it up.

Comment: Good answer, keep it up. +1

Comment: That's me! The low hanging fruit.